# Rfc2898DeriveBytes equivalent in node js

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption

Trying to translate the below C# code to nodeJS.But the results are not same. Need some help here:
C# code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "abcdef";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
}
```

Code tried in JS:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc',
  secret = 'abcdef',
  keystring = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(secret)).digest('base64').substr(0, 32);
  iv = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(secret)).digest('base64').substr(0, 16);
  inputEncoding = 'utf8',
  outputEncoding = 'base64';


function encrypt(text) {
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', keystring, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
  encrypted += cipher.final(outputEncoding);
  return encrypted;
}
```

Looking for the compatible version in node js

Comment: The codes differ (at least) in the following points: (1) In the C# code PBKDF2 is used to derive the key and IV, but not in the NodeJS code. NodeJS offers the functions `crypto.pbkdf2` (or `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`) for this purpose. By default, C# uses SHA1 and an iteration count of 1000 for PBKDF2. (2) In the C# code a 32 bytes key and thus AES-256 is used. In the NodeJS code, AES-128 is applied. (3) Note also that in the C# code the plaintext is encoded with `Encoding.Unicode` which corresponds to UTF16LE (UTF-16 in litte endian byte order). In the NodeJS code UTF8 is used for `inputEncoding`.

Comment: @Topaco Trying to incorporate your suggestions. Would this be the right approach to generate the key value?var nodeCrypto1 = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(<input>, 'utf16le'), Buffer.from("abcdef"), 1000, 32 , 'sha1');
var derivedKeyOctets1 = nodeCrypto1.toString('base64');

Comment: Not quite, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for PBKDF2 are:

```
const secret = 'abcdef';
const salt = Buffer.from([0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76]); 
const iterations = 1000;
const length = 32 + 16;
const digest = 'sha1';
const keyIV = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secret, salt, iterations, length, digest);
```

The first 32 bytes of `keyIV` are the key, the following 16 bytes the IV:

```
const key = keyIV.slice(0, 32);
const iv = keyIV.slice(32, 32 + 16);
```

In the `encrypt` method, UTF-16LE must be used as input encoding (`utf16le`) and `aes-256-cbc` as algorithm/mode:

```
const inputEncoding = 'utf16le';
const outputEncoding = 'base64';
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
function encrypt(text) {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
    encrypted += cipher.final(outputEncoding);
    return encrypted;
}
```

Test:

```
console.log(encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")); // u9JQyr8G0FbU1D+TF1ZmXNK8cMZjhL7xbhYitmXVaWNDu1hDiBY6TNUjKcza4fX99xN0f1tT3qSNHMGWTV8o2QkDnVqNQai07qAX4R2iSW/j4E8CKGwVOCWnQ46HbfWs
```

in accordance with the result of the C# code.

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks a lot.